# Iterator for-loop won't acknowledge loop finished condition

Tags: c++

This is a snippet of my program which takes a list of integers A, a number of *queries* Q (a bunch of ranges in the list to be sorted), and an index k. The list is sorted according to the queries, and afterwards the *k*th index is printed out.

Specifically:

- The list of integers is [8,5,3,9,2,4,3,1,9,7]
- The list of queries is [(0,1),(3,4),(0,4)]
- The index k is 3

Sorting A from (0,1), then (3,4), and finally (0,4) gives the final list of integers [2,3,5,8,9,4,3,1,9,7] where the *k*th index is 8, and this number is printed out.

After sorting a range of the integers, that range is recorded to avoid sorting the same range multiple times unnecessarily. These recorded ranges are stored in the variable sortedSegments.

Before sorting A according to a query, the for-loop will iterate through sortedSegments to see if the new range to sort A by has already been sorted. The problem is that the for-loop is not exiting when it should be after it iterates through all of sortedSegments.

The reason that it won't exit the loop I cannot figure out, and so I figured I would post it here so someone could point out my inevitably obvious mistake:

```
    typedef vector<pair<int,int>>   pairVec;

    bool hasOverlappingRange(pair<int,int> r1, pair<int,int> r2) {
         return (r1.first)<=(r2.second) && (r1.second)>=(r2.first);
    }

    pairVec sortedSegments;

    pairVec::iterator sit = sortedSegments.begin();
    for(sit; sit!=sortedSegments.end(); ++it) 
    { // iterate through the known ordered segments, check if query overlaps one.
        if(hasOverlappingRange( {lowIdx,highIdx} , *sit)){
            sortPortion(a, {lowIdx, highIdx}, *sit);
            segmentSorted = true;
        }
        // This is where the program breaks
    }

    if (!segmentSorted) {
        sortPortion(a, {lowIdx,highIdx},{-1,-1});
        sortedSegments.push_back( {lowIdx,highIdx} );
    }
```

I've inserted print lines throughout the code to watch the execution of the program and after running this verbose version of the code, the output is:

```
Pre-sort  A:  8 5 3 9 2 4 3 1 9 7 Segments: [] This Q: (0,1)
done checking all sorted segments
seg not sorted yet
uP:  5 sP:  8
seg sorted
new idx pushed onto segments
Post-sort A:  5 8 3 9 2 4 3 1 9 7 Segments: [ (0, 1)]

Pre-sort  A:  5 8 3 9 2 4 3 1 9 7 Segments: [ (0, 1)] This Q: (3,4)
checking if Q(3,4) overlaps (0,1)
no overlapping region here
```

But the program never completes, and the program fails when it should be exiting the for-loop. I tested the exit condition by manually incrementing the iterator where it would be incremented by the loop itself, and checking to see if the iterator equals sortedSegments.end() which it does.

Comment: *Before sorting A according to a query, the for-loop will iterate through sortedSegments to see if the new range to sort A by has already been sorted.* -- You could have used a `std::set<pair<int,int>>`instead of a `vector<int,int>`  and saved yourself from writing a loop by just calling `set::find()`.

Comment: True, but I wasn't looking for exact matches; I was just looking to cut down on the total number of integers that I would have to move in order to sort the range of the query. For instance, if the range (0,4) is sorted and the current query is (0,5), then using a set wouldn't tell me that most of the current query is already sorted and I only need to insert the 5th element into the correct position to have (0,5) sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for(sit; sit!=sortedSegments.end(); ++it)
```

Your not actually iterating throught sit.  Your iterating variable is it which I am guessing is a typo

Comment: Yup, I knew it would be an obvious mistake such as a typo. Changed it to sit and the program worked fine giving me the correct answer of 8. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Dopevoponop also, either don't use  init statement at all, or move initialization there..  you get compiler warning  about statement not having effect. Any such warning is a potetntial problem  that can occur due optimization

Comment: @Swift, do you mean to put it as `for(pairVec::iterator sit = sortedSegments.begin(); sit!=sortedSegments.end(); ++sit)`  instead of initializing outside of the for-loop?

Comment: @Dopevoponop yes, or `for(; sit!=sortedSegments.end(); ++sit)` though that is less readable. In your case you don't read value of that iterator after loop ends and reusing iterating variables when not required isn't a good style.